# The xdebug can debug in multi-files *.php

Tags: php, debugging, xdebug, designer

I configured IDE: PHP Designer with Xdebug.
But when pressing F9 for debug the php scripts.
My scripts is in multi-files.
PHP Designer with xdebug can't debug on multi-files *.PHP ?
thanks,

Comment: I'm working with Netbeans & XDebug and lots of PHP files without problems. Did you set up XDebug in php.ini in the correct way?

Comment: Dear Mr.Ocase. In netbeans, my colleagues's seminar also debug across multiple files. But NetBean is heavy and complex, I want to use php designer. It is light and fast. thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

When I add the ?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=phpD in the address bar, The php designer can debug multi files.
thanks,
http://wiki.mpsoftware.dk/doku.php/tutorials/debug_php_scripts_from_your_browser_with_phpdesigner_7_external_debugging